# Temporal Convolutional Networks (TCNs): Possibility to provide general information for each sample?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network, convolution

In my task it is important to provide general information for each sample.
A sample consists of a time sequence and there is a channel with *n* values for each time *t* of the sequence. This results in a shape of `(num_samples, num_t_in_timesequence, channels)`.

For a sample I would like to give general information that remains the same for all *t* time steps of the sample.
With *LSTMs*, for example, this is possible by initializing the hidden or cell state not with zero, but with the start information.

Is there a similar possibility with *TCNs*? And if so, where would I have to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to perform 1D convolution along time axis, right?

I assume, that by *general information* you mean a variable, or set of a few variables, characteristic for each sample.

Two inspirations from Computer Vision:

1. Add is as a separate channel and repeat the value for each time step. A bit primitive but should serve well as a baseline.
2. Use *Adaptive Instance Normalization*. It's like Batch Normalization but depends on a class (or other general information). Check formulas in the section 2.2.2 [in this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1909.09974.pdf). You would have to adopt it to 1D case.

Treat it as an inspiration, for TCN there may be different approaches as well.